# Trouble with custom Sharepoint List views created in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, list-view, list-definition

Probably something simple but i'm not sure what the problem is here.  I create several custom list views in my schema.xml for my list.  I deploy and go in sharepoint designer to make sure everything is ok.  I click on the list i created but only the FIRST view in from schema.xml is listed in the Views table.  Why are the other two not showing up?   If i delete the first list the next appears.  I want all three to be shown in the Views table.  here is the portion of schema.xml

```
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" Hidden="FALSE" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Management Users" OrderedView="TRUE" DefaultView="TRUE"  MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">10</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Photo"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Position"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LastName"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="FirstName"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Email"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="PhoneNumber"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Info"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <Where>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Group"/>
          <Value Type="Choice">Management</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Where>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="LastName" Ascending="TRUE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
  <View BaseViewID="2" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="PPM Users" OrderedView="TRUE" DefaultView="FALSE"  MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">10</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Photo"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Position"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LastName"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="FirstName"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Email"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="PhoneNumber"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Info"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <Where>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Group"/>
          <Value Type="Choice">PPM</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Where>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="LastName" Ascending="TRUE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
  <View BaseViewID="3" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="PCL Users" OrderedView="TRUE" DefaultView="FALSE"  MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">10</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Photo"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Position"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="LastName"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="FirstName"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Email"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="PhoneNumber"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Info"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <Where>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Group"/>
          <Value Type="Choice">PCL</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Where>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="LastName" Ascending="TRUE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
</Views>
```

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By just looking at your XML I noticed that you defined `Url="AllItems.aspx"` in all of your views. So every 'new' view is overwriting last one added and you end up with only one view.

You need to set different `Url` attribute for each view.

Comment: helped me lol :)